# WP Query should show No Posts when tax_query $args taxonomies don't have associated posts

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, tax-query

I have a simple query. Getting the posts only if it have both the taxonomies in it.

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'treatment',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'body-parts',
                    'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                    'terms'    => $_SESSION["body-parts"],
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'conditions',
                    'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                    'terms'    => $_SESSION["conditions"],
                ),
            ),
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'fields' => 'ids',
    );
$treatments = new WP_Query($args);
$treatment_ids_array = $treatments->posts;
var_dump($treatment_ids_array);
```

Now this array should be empty when there is no treatment (custom post type) related with both the taxonomies - instead it is showing all post ids in this array.
Otherwise everything is working correctly - when there is actually a post with both the taxonomies - then only that post is showing.

Comment: "instead it is showing all post ids" - try `var_dump( $args, $treatments->request );` and share the output, and you could also temporarily suppress all filters by adding `'suppress_filters' => true` to your args.

Comment: @SallyCJ CJ I did the var_dump as requested. Also printed the sessions as well.

Conditions: 102 Body Parts: 29

`array(4) { ["post_type"]=> string(9) "treatment" ["tax_query"]=> array(3) { ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND" [0]=> array(3) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "body-parts" ["field"]=> string(16) "term_taxonomy_id" ["terms"]=> string(2) "29" } [1]=> array(3) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "conditions" ["field"]=> string(16) "term_taxonomy_id" ["terms"]=> string(3) "102" } } ["posts_per_page"]=> int(-1) ["fields"]=> string(3) "ids" } `

Comment: @Sally  1 comment was too long
`string(564) "SELECT mod284_posts.ID FROM mod284_posts LEFT JOIN mod284_term_relationships ON (mod284_posts.ID = mod284_term_relationships.object_id) LEFT JOIN mod284_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (mod284_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( mod284_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (29) AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (102) ) AND mod284_posts.post_type = 'treatment' AND (mod284_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR mod284_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR mod284_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY mod284_posts.ID ORDER BY mod284_posts.post_date DESC "`

Comment: The query looks good to me. So with that query, were there supposed to be any results? Or should the query yield an empty array and yet it actually contained IDs of your `treatment` posts?  Have you tried using static values like `'terms' => 29`, and did the same issue persist? How about suppressing all filters - have you tried that? And are you sure this is not a caching issue?

Comment: Test 1: 102 + 29 = 0 - There is no post for these terms AND. It shows all posts.
Test 2: 96 + 9 = 197 - post ID is 197 which have both terms with id 96 AND 9.

Comment: `'suppress_filters' => true` - this did nothing for both the cases. Static values had same results. No cache.

Comment: So I know you said suppressing filters did nothing, but there's no harm trying with this: `$treatment_ids_array = get_posts( $args );` - does it also give you the same or a non-empty array that should actually be empty? Or have you already resolved the issue? How, if yes?

Comment: I don't know how it is solved, but it started working now, when $args is NULL WP_Query is supposed to return all posts I guess.

Comment: If you meant `new WP_Query( null )`, then no, nothing will be queried by default when the first parameter is *empty* (e.g. `null`, `false`, `''`). But if it's working now, then that's good. :)